# Named Parameters from C# 7.2

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing

Why does C# 7.2 support unnamed parameters after named parameters if they only can be used in the same order? Why it is not supported if the order has been changed?

From C# 7.2 method

```
public void M (int a, int b, int c, int d)

Console. WriteLine (a+b+c+d);

M (1, b : 2, 3, 4); / / output: 10

M (1, b : 2, c : 3, 4); // output: 10

M (1, c : 2, b : 3, 4); // Error
```

We are having a rule that we should not use un-named parameters after named parameters before C#

version 7.2 and that is modified from C# 7.2.

Why it is showing Error and How they are mapping internally?

Comment: If you change the order, what parameters would the unnamed arguments correspond to?

Comment: Don´t post images of code and in particular don´t post your **question** as image.

Comment: In the last example `M(1, c : 2, b : 3, 4)` the parameters are passed *out of order* and that's why there's an *ambiguity* if `1` should be assigned to `a` or `d`

Comment: We use named parameters to avoid the order it is following. In  M(1, b : 2, C : 3, 4) in this it is assigning 1 to 'a' and 4 to 'd' and why it it not mapping in the same order for M(1, c : 2, b : 3, 4) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
M (1, c : 2, b : 3, 4); // Error
```

This line throws an error because number 4 is used as a positional parameter and it is after named parameter c which is not in it position. If this code line will be entered in Visual Studio editor as part of the code below

```
namespace OptionalAndNamedParameters
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //M(1, b: 2, 3, 4);
            //M(1, b: 2, c: 3, 4);
            M(1, c: 2, b: 3, 4);//red squiggly line under 'c' and error
        }
        private static void M(int a, int b, int c, int d)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a+b+c+d);
        }
    }
}
```

under c: you'll see a red squiggly line and if you place here mouse cursor you'll see note: Named argument 'c' is used out of position but is followed by an unnamed argument. if before 4 you add d: and the analyzed code line will become

```
M(1, c: 2, b: 3, d:4);//correct code line without red squiggly line and error
```

the red squiggly line will disappear and code will be executed without errors and will get output 10.

In Microsoft documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments is the explanation for named arguments:

> - starting with C# 7.2, they're used in the correct position. In the example below, the parameter orderNum is in the correct position but isn't explicitly named.
>
>   ```
>   PrintOrderDetails(sellerName: "Gift Shop", 31, productName: "Red Mug");
>   ```
>
> However, out-of-order named arguments are invalid if they're followed by positional arguments.

According to this explanation as I understand if for number 1 will be assigned name a and code line will become:

```
M(a:1, c: 2, b: 3, 4); //red squiggly line under 'c' and error
```

It must work, but in Visual Studio editor, in this case, a red squiggly line under c will appear and the error will be thrown either. The same situation will be for line

```
M(d:1, c: 2, b: 3, 4); //red squiggly line under 'c' and error
```

That means that when you change some parameter position by naming it, all parameters which will follow after it must be named either.